# Query to fix the cricket matches from given table

Tags: sql, join

I have a table with below data

```
Country1    Country2

india       NewZealand
holland     Kenya
pak         Russia
aus         South-Africa
```

How can I fix the different number of unique matches from this table?

How to use join conditions here?
One team should play only one time with another team.

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for, please expand.

Comment: With that sample table data, what is the expected result? Can you also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: for example, how do we fetch a unique set of matches from a table, given 2 columns, and every result should be a unmatched pair..example..if County1 column has india, holland, pak, aus country2 has pak, southafrica, holland, germany..how do we assure our join conditon should fetch unique pair of matches..hope u got my question..let me know if u dont..

Comment: If both columns have the few similar country names in a table, I need to perform join condition to fetch only unique/different set of matches between every country

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: SQL server is my database

Answer (score 0):

This query should do the trick. Use of Join  with self and  Cross Join.

```
    SELECT a.country1,  b.c2 as Country2
    FROM test1  a 
    cross join 
    (SELECT country2 as c2
     FROM test1) as b
```

Comment: Hi, Country1 and Country 2 are the column names in the same table.

Comment: i have rewritten the query @Ravi

Comment: is there any way we can achieve this using <> (not equal to operator) while performing join?..because ur query will fetch duplicate matches..i mean if both columns has same data we get duplicate matches between 2 columns..any idea pls? india - kenya and kenya-india looks similar matches right?

Comment: @Ravi. Please be clear when you ask questions. The  sample data dint indicate this behaviour.